# "a lack of food/money/skills" from OALD, what am I missing?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I found this [on OALD in a definition for *lack*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lack_1):

> lack **(uncountable, singular)** - *a lack of food/money/skills*

*lack* – uncountable.

Why is the indefinite article (used for something countable) ***a*** here?

It says:

> *a lack of food; a lack of money; a lack of skills*

Comment: it's OLD @snailplane.

Comment: @snailplane Oh, in Meta Title it's OALD elsewhere it's OLD including website/URL and even the title. *COCA* I read somewhere here only and followed. But then on, I corrected myself every time I used it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this dictionary, ***[uncountable, singular]*** tells you that sometimes it's uncountable, and other times it's singular.  When it's singular (in the construction "a lack of X"), it's not uncountable.

Compare this to another definition like [that for *onomatopoeia*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/onomatopoeia), which says only ***[uncountable]***.  (Although as an aside, other dictionaries like Wiktionary list a countable sense for *onomatopoeia*.)